# Unable to write swap with a pointer

Tags: c++

I am trying to swap the first character of two strings without using any function but rather directly in `main()`. I am using pointers but I am getting an error:

> invalid conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, 
>   char>::value_type' {aka 'char'} to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
>   char *p=a[0]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a,b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    char *p=a[0];
    char *q=b[0];
    char temp=*p;
    *p=*q;
    *q=temp;
    a[0]=b[0];
    b[0]=*p;
    cout<<a<<" "<<b;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you are trying to assign a `char` value to a `char*` pointer. You are trying to assign the *value* of the `char` at `a[0]` to `p` rather than the *address* of the `char`. Likewise for `b[0]` and `q`.

Change this:

```
char *p=a[0];
char *q=b[0];
```

To this instead:

```
char *p = &a[0];
char *q = &b[0];
```

And get rid of this entirely:

```
a[0]=b[0];
b[0]=*p;
```

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    char *p = &a[0];
    char *q = &b[0];
    char temp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = temp;
    cout << a << " " << b;
    return 0;
}
```